# Sequential MySQL dumps and overwriting updated data

Tags: replication, mysql

I'm looking to do MySQL dumps on a nightly basis. I already have a solution for outputting just a diff of the data, but what I need is a way to import the data back into MySQL so the data in MySQL is UPDATED, instead of INSERTED if it's already there. For example, here's a sample table:

```
Id | User | Account_Value | Created_At | Updated_At
1  | Bob  | $100          | 2009-01-01 | 2009-01-01
2  | Ed   | $200          | 2009-01-01 | 2009-01-01
```

Then the next day, the table looks like this:

```
Id | User | Account_Value | Created_At | Updated_At
1  | Bob  | $50           | 2009-01-01 | 2009-01-02
2  | Ed   | $200          | 2009-01-01 | 2009-01-01
```

When I do the data export on the second day, it will correctly output something like:

```
INSERT into ACCOUNTS VALUES (1,'Bob', '$50', '2009-01-01', '2009-01-02')
```

However, this will conflict with what's already there. What I want is to have it overwrite what's already there. Thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add the "on duplicate key update" clause to the insert statements:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Comment: Sigh. That was easy. Well done.